# horizontal divider between button group in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put some text between a radio button group....I have tried both

```
<hr>
```

and

```
<br>
```

tag. But it doesn't work... The text always sticks to the button group..This is my code

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" data-toggle="buttons">

          <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"> MP3</span></label>
         <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"> WAV</span></label>

<hr>
<p>Use conversion tools</p>

<label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"> MKV</span></label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"> FLV</span></label>
 </div>
```

My intention is to create some gap or using a divider between group choice.

Comment: Try add `<br>` before `<hr>` and see the difference.

Comment: it doesn't work....although i have got my solution...thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try thiss:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try to use:

```
<hr class="separator">
```

This is what is on bootstrap docs.

Answer (score 7):

you can also use

```css
<hr class="featurette-divider">
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not clear, would be better if you had jsfiddle or screenshot, 
you should use form control, or at least list control to order elements as you want

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"></div>
</div>
```

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5658/ maybe helps.

Comment: Though my intention is being fulfilled by your answer...radio button option doesn't work...thanks for your endeavor

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- HR -->
<div class='col-sm-12 pb-3'>
    <hr>
</div>
```